# Why do I have to run 'source .zsh' everytime I want to run a command script in terminal?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I created a script to connect to a vpn and stored it in /usr/local/bin on OSX Catalina. I then created an alias in the file ~/.zsh - all working as expected at this point. However, whenever I open the terminal and type in the alias, I get "zsh: command not found: myAlias". I have to run `source .zsh` then input the Alias to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the contents of the command script:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sstpc --log-stderr... rest of code to connect to vpn
```

My alias is written as this:

```
alias myAlias='. /usr/local/bin/myScript.command'
```

Comment: The configuration file is `~/.zshrc`, not `~/.zsh`.

Comment: so just copy the alias in ~/.zsh and paste into ~/.zshrc? Thank you. If you want all the internet points, mark as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Well, renaming `~/.zsh` to `~/.zshrc` would be simpler. I make `.zsh` a directory in which I keep all my `zsh`-related configuration files, and make `~/.zshrc` a symlink to `~/.zsh/zshrc`.

Comment: Also, if you are sourcing `myScript.command`, there's no point in adding a shebang to the file, and especially a shebang that specifies `/bin/bash`.

Comment: so remove the shebang completely? It works as is, and have applied the alias to .zshrc I ran source .zshrc one time and now with a new terminal window I just enter myAlias and it works as expected.

Comment: There is nearly no point of putting a shebang into a file which is intended to be sourced. What effect should it have? There is one exception: Many text editors derive the file type used for syntax highlighting from a shebang line, and for this it would make sense. But then, you should not call it _bash_, since it is obviously not a bash script (since you are sourcing it from Zsh, not bash).